# How do I add density or heat map to this scatter plot?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I have a scatter plot using C3js.

The X axis has the number of interactions and the Y axis is the days/time when those interactions happened.

Now the scatter plot works fine for this data. But now I want to take it further such that if the number of interactions is more, then the nodes are green and if the number of interactions are less, they are red. The scaling of the colors has to be gradient as interactions density increases from less to more.

Below is the basic code :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
point: {
    r: 5
},
data: {
    xs: {
        Safe: 'ibm_x',
        Losing: 'microsoft_x',
    },

    columns: [
        ["ibm_x", 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7],
        ["microsoft_x", 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2.0, 3.0, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3.0, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8],
        ["Safe", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5],
        ["Losing", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, ],
    ],
    type: 'scatter'
},
color: {
    pattern: ['#49B5A6', '#F86A52']
},
 axis: {
    x: {
        label: 'Interactions',
        tick: {
            fit: false
        }
    },
    y: {
        label: 'Days'
    }
},
```

});

Below is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/npmarkunda/qx35z8n5/

I'm attaching an image for the results that are expected.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C3 has nothing to offer this feature. So need to use d3 to get it through.

```
//on chart load
chart.load({done: function() {
      //merge the first two columns which decide the x axis. 
      var g = data[0].concat(data[1])
      //get the max min in the concatenated array
        var minmax = d3.extent(g.filter(function(d){ return !isNaN(d);}));
      //make ascale for color range
      //min is '#49B5A6'
      //max is '#F86A52'
      var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(minmax)
        .range(['#49B5A6', '#F86A52']);
      //iterate each circle  
      d3.selectAll("circle")[0].forEach(function(c){
        var d1 = d3.select(c).data()[0];//get data for circle
        change color on timeout
        window.setTimeout(function(){d3.select(c).style("fill", color(d1.x))}, 500);

      });
    },});
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qx35z8n5/2/).

Comment: @JimmyPaul you can do it by c3js. I forked your jsfiddle and made some changes. let me know if this is what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/DreamRunner/71ov1jgw/1/

Comment: I have already accepted @cyril's answer. It worked for me. But thanks for looking into it again.

Answer (score 1):

c3 has a `color` configuration that allows you to specify a function to calculate the color of each point.

I've borrowed heavily from Cyril's answer and used this configuration option:

```
var data = [
    ["ibm_x", 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, ...],
    ["microsoft_x", 3.2, 3.2, ...],
    ["Safe", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, ...],
    ["Losing", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, ...],
];

// Get all the x values
var g = data[0].concat(data[1])

//get the max min in the concatenated array
var minmax = d3.extent(g.filter(function(d){ return !isNaN(d);}));

//make a scale for color range
//min is '#49B5A6'
//max is '#F86A52'
var heat = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(minmax)
    .range(['#49B5A6', '#F86A52']);

c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: data,
        ...
        color: function (color, d) {
            return heat(d.x);
        },
    },
    ...
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qx35z8n5/4/ (again modified from Cyril's answer)